# How can I determine if upgrading a dependency will break a jar file?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, semantic-versioning

ore.spongepowered.org is a website that hosts Minecraft Plugins.

These Plugins rely upon a dependency called SpongeAPI in order to run.

Given a jar file that has been uploaded to our service, and has metadata that associates it with a given (semver) dependency on SpongeAPI, How can we determine if there is a binary incompatible change in SpongeAPI that affects a given plugin?

E.g. A plugin jar is published for API version 5.

API 5.1 (semver) is released, it contains only additions. As long as semver has been enforced, we know due to versioning convention that the plugin will likely work.

API 6 gets released, it's a semver major release, but the jar was built against API5, there is a possibility that the plugin is still compatible, but no guarantee. How can we test (using tooling) whether the plugin has any references to code that was removed or had it's signature changed from API 5 -> API 6 ?

This would be valuable to know, as we could warn people when they are using a potentially incompatible combination.

Note: We are in control of the Library SpongeAPI not the plugins that are community made.

Comment: Comprehensive test coverage?

Comment: Run the integration test suite.

Comment: Note that "API 5.1" and "API 6" do not contain SemVer compliant version strings.

Comment: The full version string is API 5.1.0 and 6.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conventional approach is to build the system using automated build and continuous integration tools like Jenkins, Bitbucket Pipelines, Gitlab-CI etc. (I presume you are using Maven or Gradle already given that you have tagged them in your question).

The build will fail if the change (to a newer dependency) changed anything like method signatures or other refactoring.

Furthermore, you should also have unit tests ensuring that your functionality is working as expected. If a fundamental behaviour of the underlying libraries changes that affects your functions, you would be able to detect that too. This would help you catch functional changes, not just compilation issues.

Finally, you might want to look at the new Java 9 module system. It's still a bit behind with regards to adoption, but it might offer an alternative solution to what you are looking for, especially if you are in control of the dependencies too.

Comment: The problem is, this is external jars that people have uploaded, so we are in control of the dependency, but not of the files that people are uploading. Furthermore, they may have additional dependencies that arn't designated by build scripts, dependencies on other plugins etc.

Comment: Do the plugins have some kind of entry point? Some standard interface that will always be present? Can you have an automated script which tries to build a reference project with just the plugin Jar against the API versions you want to verify it with? And then maybe as an extra step call the methods of the standard entry point as a very rudimentary integration test to check that the plugin initialises as expected? Additional dependencies shouldnt be an issue if you are using Maven / Gradle, it will download them too when building your test project.

Comment: They do, but I'm viewing this as something completely external. Since executing that code could potentially open you up to more problems like getting the servers compromised.

I'm thinking something akin to a static linker, or some sort of analyzer.

Comment: If you have access to the source of the plugin, you can pull it from its repo and build it (without running it). If it is already compiled, it is a bit more challenging, because you will only get `NoSuchMethodError` when the missing / modified method is invoked. That's were integration tests would help. I guess you could have a look at how IDEs like IntelliJ perform static analysis of code structure. You will have to decode the class files of the plugin though to know what methods they are calling inside.

Comment: "If you have access to the source of the plugin, you can pull it from its repo and build it (without running it)."
1. That implies we have access to the source.
2. The build plugins / systems / scripts could also potentially be malware.

Comment: Yeah but don't expect a single perfect solution to handle all scenarios. You have to break it down and maybe have tiers of verification. If you have access to the source t can get a full build verification. If you don't, then you can have a more limited initial verification, that just calls the known entry points of the plugin if such exist. Re malware, you can just run things in a VM or docker, sandboxed without any network access, and delete it after the process, on a dedicated host. You can finally do static analysis, not sure if PMD or FindBugs provides what you are looking for though.

Comment: Essentially what we need I suspect, is a form of static linker, that knows the package names of the dependencies we provide.

Comment: OK, if you believe that is the approach, have a look at this list to start from somewhere and see if any of the tools could suit you to get started: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java

Answer (score 0):

Even if every component in your dependency tree adhere's perfectly to SemVer standards, you still need out-of-band (relevant to SemVer) information to have closure on the transient dependencies.  The dependency graph in general and the diamond point dependency problem in particular, are known hard problems.  Testing can put a small, but very expensive dent in it, but is generally prohibitive for any non-trivial product running on servers with hundreds or thousands of components.

The best that you can do is containerize the environment around your application and test only the interesting combinations of dependent components therein, releasing only those combinations that pass your product's entire test suite.  Then you can say "here's a box that has our functional X pre-configured and we make no claims of compatibility with any other products or combinations of component versions".  Application specific VM's are the best at reducing the problem space to economically manageable surfaces. Even somewhat leaky environments like app containers can help tame this tiger.